# Same XPath attribute test for multiple tags

Tags: html, xml, xpath

This XPath expression finds all `a` elements that contain the text `Let's meet at 9 o'clock`:

```
//a[text()=concat('Let', "'", 's meet at 9 o', "'", 'clock')]
```

How can I change the XPath expression so that not only `a` tags are found but also `div` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath:

```
//*[(name()='a' or name()='div') and text()=concat('Let', "'", 's meet at 9 o', "'", 'clock')]
```

Comment: You're missing the `()` on one of those `name`s.

Comment: @JLRishe. Right. Thanks

Comment: Trying to learn something new here: so if a web element does not have a name attribute, the name is the tagname itself?  If so, good to know.

Comment: @BillHileman, `name()` is not the same as `@name`. If we have something like `<input name="qwerty">`, then we can use both `//*[name()="input"]` and `//*[@name="qwerty"]`

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  I definitely learned something new from that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `self::` axis to check for either `a` or `div`, plus your other predicate:

```
//*[self::a or self::div][text()=concat('Let', "'", 's meet at 9 o', "'", 'clock')]
```

Comment: Does this have any advantages or disadvantages compared to the other answer?

Comment: Also useful.  Is perhaps this xpath version specific vs. name() ?

Comment: I prefer to use the `self::` axis directly (rather than indirectly via a function call that returns a string) as I feel it's a bit more direct and concise expression of intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
//(a | div)[. = concat('Let', "'", 's meet at 9 o', "'", 'clock')]
```